# Specialized Textbox to populate specific types in property window during design time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

Here's the **background of the problem**.

We have our own ORM framework for development of .net applications. Now we are trying to create specialized UI objects to work tightly with the ORM. We have created an interface called IBindable which is implemented on all UI controls. We started with textbox webcontrol of asp.net. First we created TextBox class deriving from System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox which also implements IBindable interface.

IBindable is responsible to hold key binding information for ORM.

1. **EntityType**
2. **EntityFields**

EntityType is the type of buiness-object within the ORM and EntityField is particular property of the EntityType business-object to which it will bind to at run-time.

Now the **actual problem** is,

During the design time, we wish to populate all available business objects in the project for the textbox property EntityType within the propert-window of TextBox. After the user selects given entity type we need populate properties of selected EntityType for corresponding EntityField property.

> Please note that all our business
>   objects or Entity objects derive from
>   **EntityBase** abstract class.

Comment: You should really consider using an "Extender Provider" instead of subclassing every UI element: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider.aspx

Comment: It seems IExtenderProvider provider primarily works for windows forms. Does it support asp.net ?

Comment: It does, although the designer support is a bit lame. We did something similar (also for data binding, in the old days of .net 1.0) and ended up setting the properties in code rather than in the designer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to attach an **Editor** to your properties. In your custom TextBox, you can assign the editor to your property using the [EditorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute.aspx):

```
[Editor(typeof(EntityTypeChooser), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public property EntityType { ... }
```

Of course, you will have to implement your `EntityTypeChooser`: You inherit from [UITypeEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.aspx) and override the `EditValue` method.

Examples:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Property_Editor.aspx